# How to reset the $PATH in terminal OS X El Capitan? tried previous posts but did not work

Tags: macos, python, path

I accidentally messed up my $PATH. I Tried to follow the instructions from the previous similar questions but I keep having the same problem
When I type: 
echo$ PATH, 
I get the following response:
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin . Do you know how i can reset the PATH?  The operating system is OS X El Capitan. Thank you so much

Comment: What exactly did you try from the linked post?

Answer (score 1):

First, run `PATH=/bin:/usr/bin` in Terminal.

Then open `~/.bash_profile` (in terminal, `nano/vim/favorite editor ~/.bash_profile`) or open Finder, then press Shift+Command+G and paste it in. Then you can comment out the path line. There is no need to delete .bash_profile in its entirety, and it isn't recommended.

Comment: I typed: PATH=/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin . When i open the .bash profile i do see the same path: PATH=/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin . however when i close and reopen the terminal and type: echo $PATH , the same old PATH appears. Dont know whats wrong. Tried to troubleshoot it but have the same problem. Thank you so much for your response

Comment: This might be simple but did you save?

Comment: I haven't faced this problem recently. Maybe restart? Try again? Use a diff editor? The standard 9 yards...

Comment: I tried it before but it did not work.

Comment: Tried login-logout or accepting the answer?

Comment: I did try to login-log out but it did not work

Comment: Try source ~/.bash_profile in terminal

Comment: -sh: /Users/myusername/.bash_profile: No such file or directory

Comment: Type source in the terminal then drag the actual file from the finder

Comment: -sh: source: filename argument required
source: usage: source filename [arguments]

Comment: did not work for some reason

Comment: Try to restart? I don't know at this point... My suggestions above usually fixed the problem.

Comment: echo $PATH #figured out that it directs me to the .profile instead of the .bash_profile. Can this be the problem? Also if I open the .profile with a text edit, its written that The original version is saved in .profile.pysave. Can i retrieve the original version?

Comment: I don't know. Can you access the `.profile.pysave` you were mentioning?

Comment: FIXED it! Thank you much for your advises! Actually the PATH name never changed. It was the .profile name instead of the .bash profile which remained the same! thank you much